# Number of ways one can express $2^2 3^3 5^5 7^7$ as the product of two numbers $ (a,b)$ such that they are co-prime and $1 <a < b$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, permutations

> The number of ways one can express $2^2 3^3 5^5 7^7$ as the product of two numbers $ (a,b)$ such that they are co-prime and $1 < a <
> b$ is?

My attempt :- Now as the number as coprime the possible combination of factors would be

Type i) $a$ is the product of one unique prime number, with $b$ being that of the other 3. There are 4 such combinations ($c(4,1)$ possible combinations).

Type ii) $a$ is the product of any 2 primes and $b$ is that of the other 2. There are $c(4,2)$ such combinations.

Type (iii) $a$ is the product of any 3 primes, and $b$ is the only remaining prime, again there are $c(4,3)=c(4,1)$ such combinations.

Which gives us $14$.

However, all the options (this is a MCQ) are less than or equal to $8$. What am I doing wrong?

Source :- ISI 2021 UG entrance exam

Comment: Worth emphasis: a correct solution must *explicitly* invoke FTA = existence and uniqueness of prime factorizations (or equivalent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are missing is that this way, you found the number of all ordered pairs $(a,b)$ of coprime numbers distinct from $1$ such that $ab=2^2 3^3 5^5 7^7.$ Only half of them satisfy $a<b.$

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach:

Let $~a,b,c,d~$ equal $~2^2,~3^3, ~5^5, 7^7,~$ respectively.

Let $~R~$ denote the set $~\{a,b,c,d\},~$ let $~S~$ denote any subset of $~R,~$ (including $~R~$ itself, and the empty set), and let $~T~$ denote the set $~(R - S).$

Temporarily ignore the two constraints that

- $~1 < ~$ both factors.
- The first factor must be less than the second factor.

Then, there are $~2^4~$ possible subsets $~S~$, and each subset $~S~$ generates a distinct product, where you take the product of the elements of $~S~$ as one factor, and the product of the elements of $~T~$ as the other factor.

This type of construction of factors is required because the two factors are required to be relatively prime, and because the product of the two factors is required to be the product of the elements in $~R.$

Adjusting for the fact that the first factor must be less than the second factor is accomplished by recognizing that for each product of factors $~a \times b,~$ the product of factors $~b \times a~$ will also be present.  Exactly one of the two products will have the first factor less than the second factor.

So, this takes us to the computation of $~\dfrac{2^4}{2}.$

Then, you have to deduct $~1~$ because both factors are required to be $~> 1,~$ which implies that the *smaller* factor can not be represented by the empty set.

Answer (score 0):

The one of $a$ and $b$ that has $2^2$ as a factor may or may not also have $3^3$ as a factor. Either way, it may or may not also have $5^5$ as a factor. And in **almost** any of those four cases, it may or may not also $7^7$ as a factor. The *almost* is because if you had all four of $2^2$, $3^3$, $5^5$,and $7^7$ together in what would have to be $b$, that would force $a=1$. So the number of pairs $(a,b)$ you’re seeking is $2^3-1=7$.

Answer (score 0):

If you notice (quick pencil and paper estimate) that $7^7$ is vastly greater than $2^23^35^5$, then you realize that $b$ (being $>a$) always contains $7^7$ as a factor, and when $b$ contains $7^7$ it will be larger than $a$ however the other factors are arranged. So $b$ can contain just $7^7$ in one way, or $b$ can contain $7^7$ and one other exponentiated prime in three ways, or $b$ can contain $7^7$ and two other exponentiated prime factors in three ways. $b$ cannot contain all four exponentiated prime factors because $a>1$. Altogether, $b$ can be formulated in seven ways.